# enter key for save textarea values

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

hi i have ckeditor and one button for save ckeditor text whith ajax .

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
<input type="button" name="send" id="send" value="Send" onclick="save()">
```

i want remove button and when key press enter save text whith ajax ( run save function )
but when press enter in ckeditor line break . and how use enter exchange button?

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
if (enter press in any where web page ) do save();
```

Comment: Listen to the keypress event on the body, check if it is enter. If it is enter, save the form. This sounds like a very bad idea though, it changes the normal usage of a textarea and may interfere with keyboard navigation

Comment: You may want to use an `input` instad of a `textarea`.

Comment: how use ckeditor for input text? for enter event can insert complete code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important part is that the content in CKEditor is an iframe, so those solutions that try to check key presses on the current document will fail.

The solution is as simple as this using the CKEditor events and without relying on any external library:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');  

editor.on('key', function(ev) {
   if (ev.data.keyCode==13)
   {
       ev.cancel();
       console.log('enter');
   }       
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zjkSR/
(look at your console)

Answer (score 1):

This is code I created for a site a while back, it allows you to submit on enter, however will allow you to hold shift+enter to create a new line (as text areas that auto submit should).

It's written using jQuery.

```
    var  TextBox = $('.autosubmit');
    var code =null;
    // on keypress do this
    TextBox.keyup(function(e)
    {
        // get keycode
        code= (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        // if keycode is 13 (enter)
        if (code == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
            var content = this.value;
            var caret = getCaret(this);
            this.value = content.substring(0,caret)+"\n"+content.substring(carent,content.length-1);
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else if (code == 13) {
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        }
    });

    function getCaret(el) {
      if (el.selectionStart) {
         return el.selectionStart;
      } else if (document.selection) {
         el.focus();

       var r = document.selection.createRange();
       if (r == null) {
        return 0;
       }

        var re = el.createTextRange(),
        rc = re.duplicate();
        re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);

        return rc.text.length;
      }  
      return 0;
     }
```

However, I'm not certain it will work inside CK Editor. The best way to do this would be to add something like this to your config file:

```
config.keystrokes = 
[
    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 121 /*F10*/, 'toolbarFocus' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 122 /*F11*/, 'elementsPathFocus' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 121 /*F10*/, 'contextMenu' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 90 /*Z*/, 'undo' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 89 /*Y*/, 'redo' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 90 /*Z*/, 'redo' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 76 /*L*/, 'link' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 66 /*B*/, 'bold' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 73 /*I*/, 'italic' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 85 /*U*/, 'underline' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 109 /*-*/, 'toolbarCollapse' ],
    [ 13, 'save'] // note this line
];
```

which will add the `save` event on enter, but will keep the other default keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is capture the `keyup` or `keydown` event with jQuery, and check the `keyCode` of the `event` to see if it was the enter key that was pressed.

Eg:

```
$('body').on('keyup', function(event){
    if (event.keyCode===13)
    {
        alert('enter key pressed!');
        save();
    }
});
```

Javascript keyCode reference: http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Edit: oops, misread question - see updated answer. Changed selector to target body instead of the textarea, but as @KevinB said, probably a bad idea.

Comment: i test this code "$('#editor1').on('keyup', function(event)...." but not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    //set up the editor instance for ckeditor
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(
       'editor1',
        {
            toolbar:
            [
                ['Source'],
                ['Cut', 'Copy', 'PasteText'],
                ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'],
                ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink'], ['SpecialChar']
            ]
        }
    );    

    $('body').on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.target.id !== "editor1" && (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) === 13) 
        {
            alert(e.target.id); // jquery ajax  save function
        }
    });
});

<textarea id="editor1" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: -1 I dislike code without explanation... please add some to get +1

Comment: what the user want is on enter key event (but not in textarex) text box value should be save.

Comment: when focuse on textarea do not show anything i should focuse on web page and enter

Comment: i can not understand. what u want to do?

Comment: but whith focuse in ckeditor and press enter line break yet and should focuse in webpage :(