# CKEDITOR Send Content When Enter KeyPressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, jquery-events

I want to create chat on web base. I use CKEDITOR for B,I,U,font type, font size just like Yahoo Messenger or other IM

I've succeed catching the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, but I got this error when I call:

```
my_ckeditor_inctance_obj.setData('');
```

I call this because when press <kbd>enter</kbd> text will gone just like other chat program (FB, YM, etc)

I used Chrome. Chrome's console said:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'equals' of null ckeditor.js:36
> // Detail Error
> d.range.getCommonAncestor ckeditor.js:36
> (anonymous function) ckeditor.js:133
> s ckeditor.js:54
> j.enterkey.enterBlock ckeditor.js:53
> (anonymous function)

BUT, I used button send too. When I click send, it work perfectly.

This my source code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Init CKEDITOR
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',{
    toolbar:[['Bold','Italic','Underline'],['Font','FontSize'],['TextColor','BGColor']]
});

// Handle for keypress. In this case is When ENTER key is press
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].on('contentDom', function() {
    this.document.on('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.data.getKey() == 13){ // Do this code when ENTER is pressed
                var temp=getContent();
                console.log(temp);
        }
    });
});
});

function getContent(){
// Get the editor instance that you want to interact with.
var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;

// Get editor contents
// http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData
var temp=oEditor.getData();

//set to blank again
oEditor.setData(''); // This code make error --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'equals' of null ckeditor.js:36 BUT when click 'send' button this error didn't show.(send button use this function)
return temp;
}
```

How to fix that problem?

UPDATE:
I found solution in here [enter key for save textarea values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602647/enter-key-for-save-textarea-values)

Special thanks to [AlfonsoML](https://stackoverflow.com/users/250294/alfonsoml)

Comment: I just copied the code and tested it. I didn't receive any errors in either Chrome 20.0.1132.57 or Firefox 14.0.1. Using CkEditor 3.6.1 with jquery-1.4.4

Comment: This code above is just my snippet not full of my code. Do you want my full code?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not working on chat. I wanted to let you know that the code you posted doesn't cause an error. You might want to try stripping down your code to see if you still get the error. If not, you could add portions back until you find what's causing the error.

Comment: @codewaggle: Btw thx for your reply. I found another solution. And it work.

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [enter key for save textarea values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602647/enter-key-for-save-textarea-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [enter key for save textarea values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602647/enter-key-for-save-textarea-values)